# infinite loop prefix/prefix python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

in the following python code i am triying to collect parts of word based on it existance in a list `prefix_list` in a specific order from the right to the left ,
the way things should happen :

for the word : `timaezaho` for example

`right` : contains len of letters i want to work with from the right

`prefix_list` : list of the prefix combinaision of 2 letters, or just one letter

this is my code :

```
#word="timazaho"  right=4 
p = prefix = word[-right:] # p== "zaho"
while right>= 0:            
    while p != "" and p not in self.prefix_list :
        if len (p) == 1: 
            break
        else :
            p = p[-len(p)+1:] #1st iteration p=="aho"

    if p in  self.prefix_list: # "aho" in self.prefix_list
        self.l_prefix.append(p)
        right = right - len(p)    #right = 1
        p = word[-right:]   # p = "z"
    else : 
        break
```

the problem is that the program doesn't stop i don't know why i used a debugger to know whats wrong it s stuck in the second while

Comment: You should add complete information. Please add the value of `self.prefix_list`. Also please explain in a comment that why you don't update the value of the `prefix` variable.

Comment: the problem is in the prefix variable i didn't modifie it by mistake